# Maximum security level for TYPO3 backend and frontend authentification

Tags: security, typo3, rsa

In TYPO3 there are several possible security levels for FE and BE authentication.

As I could notice, the maximum security level is "rsa", but what is the used key size ?

As some experts recommends to use minimum 2048 bit "The absolute minimum size for n is 2048 bits or so if you want to protect your data for 20 years. [...] If you can afford it in your application, let n be 4096 bits long, or as close to this size as you can get it." (p. 233) // Practical Cryptography (2003), Ferguson & Schneier

Ref. : http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_key_length.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key size depends on your system environment.

The TYPO3 RSA Auth service first checks, if PHP is compiled with OpenSSL support. If so, it uses `openssl_pkey_new` to create the key pair ([source](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/rsaauth/Classes/Backend/PhpBackend.php#L40)). According to the PHP documentation, `openssl_pkey_new` requires a valid OpenSSL config file, which usually comes with the PHP version installed. You can find out the location of the OpenSS default config by using the `phpinfo()` function. In the config file, the setting `default_bits` represents the default key size used to generate new keys. Usually, most Linux distributions ship with a config, where the default key size is set to 2048 bit

If PHP is not compiled with OpenSSL support, then the TYPO3 RSA Auth service tries to use OpenSSL on command line to create a key pair. The key size in this case is hardcoded to 1024 bit ([source](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/rsaauth/Classes/Backend/CommandLineBackend.php#L98))

Answer (score 1):

rsa (coming from the system extension "rsaauth") allows to transfer your credentials not in plaintext, however using SSL for all connections makes that part and also the use of this extension fully obsolete. I'd recommend using HTTPS instead.

Comment: This is really a comment and not an answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks Benni. Indeed, I would like to know the key size.